# How to make mat-button-toggle-group as read only mode

Tags: javascript, angular

We can make the input field as read only mode using the `[readonly]="true"` directives, in the same is it possible to make the mat-toggle-group as readonly mode,

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" [readonly]="true">
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

I don't want to make it as disabled. If it is disabled during the form submission I can't access this value. Readonly means user don't change the value if it is already set.

Answer (score 4):

Well I'm not sure if even the disabled attribute will work. Angular team doesn't seem to care as it's not a native element like button or input so browser doesn't understand it. [see this](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18563)

Only solution I can think of is using css, add a conditional style, setting `pointer-events: none` on the mat-button-toggle-group and `pointer-events: auto;`  to re-enable it, which will make it unclickable but still retaining its properties and value. This will require some additional highlight though for user to understand that its set to readonly.
Note that some old browsers and IE10 and below does not support this.

Comment: This gets messy if your [disabled] is long, but works to actually disable the button.
<mat-button-toggle [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events' : ( isDisabled ) ? 'none' : 'auto}'}" [disabled]="isDisabled"

Answer (score 2):

`Disabled` attribute is working.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sv6soq?file=src/app/button-toggle-appearance-example.html)

Comment: If it is disabled, then the problem we can't pass these values during the form submission

Comment: If you bind the form element with the component, it should work. Can you share stackblitz code of the form example?